# GPU instanced mesh does not render for a camera that is strictly being rendered by Camera.Render()

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics

Mesh does not render when camera is called strictly with Camera.Render(). As in the camera component is disabled. Mesh is being drawn with Graphics.DrawMeshInstanced()

In this video, the lightning is the mesh not rendering. When I disable the camera component, the camera is resorting to the manual rendering call in my script. You can ignore where it says "No camera rendering". The camera is rendering to a texture.

https://imgur.com/gPW2ZTA

Pipeline: URP
Unity Version: 2021.3.10f1